# Custom report using TestNG listeners

Tags: report, testng, listeners

I am trying to prepare a custom report using TestNG listeners.I am using IReporter interface of TestNG listener.How can I get exception details using testNG listeners.Or is it better use
ITestListener to get the exception details

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any best way, just whatever works for you.  I am getting it via TestListenerAdapter's onFinish() method:

```
List<ITestResult> failedTests = this.getFailedTests();
Iterator <ITestResult> iter = failedTests.iterator();

while (iter.hasNext()) {
    ITestResult aResult = iter.next();
    System.out.println(aResult.getMethod().getMethodName());
    System.out.println(aResult.getThrowable().getMessage());
}
```